# Java8 and Daylight Savings Time

Tags: java, java-8, dst, java-time

I am currently writing an application where I need to check if there were any files created before yesterday and clean them up. At the moment when I try the below:

```
LocalDateTime today = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay();
long todayEpoch = today.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).toEpochSecond() * 1000;
```

and convert the milliseconds back to a Date (on any online millisecond to date converter) it tells me I am 1 hour behind.

This is because of Daylight Savings Time, which means we are GMT+1:00 which probably explains the 1 hour difference.

To solve this I had to do change the Zone Id to UTC as below:

```
final LocalDateTime today = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay();
long todayEpoch = today.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toEpochSecond() * 1000;
```

But I am still confused how it worked.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: How are you getting the file creation date? If those are files on disk, why not use a `FileTime` object, retrieved with `Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime()`? From that you get an `Instant` that you can compare with `Instant.now().minusDays(1)`, there are no time-zones involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LocalDateTime today = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay();
```

returns today (in your time zone) at 00:00. So if today is 10 June 2016, this will return `2016-06-10 00:00`.

```
today.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))
```

adds the time zone information to the date, which becomes: `2016-06-10 00:00 Europe/London`, which is the same instant as `2016-06-09 23:00 UTC`, due to British Summer Time.

You then retrieve the epoch seconds, which is the number of seconds elapsed between the 1st of January 1970 at 00:00 UTC and that instant.

In your second example, you calculate the millis between the epoch and `2016-06-10 01:00 Europe/London` or `2016-06-10 00:00 UTC`.

You need to decide which you want.

Comment: Thanks @assylias for the detailed explanation. Its beginning to make sense now.